# CAML query not retrieving items based on Start date and end date for EST Time zone?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, custom-list, caml-query

I have one custom list name Test, Using the Following query

```
SPList PollList = web.Lists["Test"];
SPQuery PollQuery = new SPQuery();
var CurrentDate = DateTime.Today;

PollQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='StartDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + CurrentDate + "</Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + CurrentDate + "</Value></Geq></And></where>";
```

the above querying retrieving the items for IST Time but it not retrieving the items for EST Time zone. Please Suggest me an idea to solve this issue

Comment: You can refer this link how to handle datetime in CAML query. https://yieldreturnpost.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/caml-query-utc-date-comparisons-in-sharepoint/. I have not tried but believe it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct date format to pass in your CAML query is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`.

In case its javascript, you can convert date as below:

```
var inputDate = new Date();
string formattedDate = inputDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

In case its is SSOM, you have 2 options

1) `<Today />` operator. If you use this, your CAML would be as below:

```
PollQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='StartDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Geq></And></Where>";
```

2) You also have the inbuilt `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime()` method.For that you need to add the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities` namespace for that. You CAML query would be as below:

```
PollQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Leq><FieldRef Name='StartDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Today) + "</Value></Leq><Geq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Today) + "</Value></Geq></And></Where>";
```

Comment: hey @Suriya, did you try this approach ? is it working for you ?